# Docker NetCore(microservices) + React

Tags: reactjs, docker, .net-core

I have some

a) .Net Core API's (microservices) projects listening on ports 5001, 6001 and

b)  a react front end application listening on 3000.

I was wondering, if I should setup a Nginx (reverse proxy) on Digital Ocean, that calls each of these services based on the URL filtering. Something like [http:// /api] --> going to an api gateway, which further hits the specific microservice. All other request to that domain forwarded to react.

or is there a better way.

My problem is there is a possibility I might deploy more websites on the same DigitalOcean droplet and my Nginx, configuration will just explode -- wondering if I could have just forward all the requests for one domain go to a container that would do the orchestration for me.

Also, I am still a bit unsure how the development workflow looks like -- I am building github actions to build / deploy my containers; any pointers would help.

Comment: I would suggest taking a look into Kubernetes and what it does to orchestrate multiple containers.

Comment: I think even if its Kubernetes; I will still need a unique port per service; and then have a api gateway in kubernetes that handles routing. Also, when I read up on Kubernetes it seems like its a managed service that I need to buy.  Just confused around how the development workflow is working for everyone.